# Conditioned absolute deviation around the median

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate the MAD (median absolute deviation) of a dataset.
The formula without criterium is as follows:

```
=Median(Abs(D27:Z34-Median(D27:Z34)))
```

Where D27:Z34 is an array of numbers.

However, there are certain cells that need to be excluded based on the values in another array.

The conditional Median I can already calculate using the following array formula:

```
MEDIAN(IF(D5:Z12=AC5;D27:Z34)))
```

Where D5:Z12 is the text dataset, AC5 is the criterium and D27:Z34 is the array containing the actual data.

I thought it would be possible to combine the formulas to something like the following:

```
=MEDIAN(ABS(IF(D5:Z12=AC5;D27:Z34)-MEDIAN(IF(D5:Z12=AC5;D27:Z34))))
```

But sadly this doesn't work.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Some example data:

```
N   N   N
N   N   N
Y   Y   Y
N   N   N

3   8   9
5   4   3
2   10  1
4   1   1

MAD=    1
```

If the condition would be Y, the MAD of the corresponding values (2,10,1) should be calculated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if you can provide some test data?

Comment: Yes sorry, made a reference error. Fixed it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the first if condition to before ABS would make it work

`{=MEDIAN(IF(D5:Z12=AC5,ABS(D27:Z34-MEDIAN(IF(D5:Z12=AC5,D27:Z34)))))}`

This is an array formula, enter this formula in the cell and press Cntrl+shift+Enter

In your original formula, the difference is calculated with median (0-median) if the condition is not satisfied

Comment: FWIW: For the future viewers, this is an array formula and must be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.  I assume the OP knows this but future readers may not.

Comment: Well....many of the visitors to this site do not know what the `{}` means or how to make them appear.  Many will assume that they have to type them in.  My personal preference is to not put the `{}` around the formula my self but explain how to get Excel to put them.